# Using fuzzing lib (python)

Tags: python, string, fuzzing

I'm trying to use this library : http://pastebin.com/xgPXpGtw (an example of use: http://pastebin.com/fNFAW3Fh)
I have some issues since I dont want to split in an array all the byte as he does.

My test script looks like this:

```
import random
from random import *

def onerand(packet):
    pack  = packet[:]
    byte = str(chr(choice(range(256))))
    pack[choice(range(len(packet)))]= byte
    print "fuzzing rand byte:%s\n" % (byte.encode("hex"))
    return pack

test = "\x63\x63\x63\x63\x63\x63\x63\x63\x63\x63\x63\x63\x63\x63"

while True:
   print onerand(test)
```

And actually returns :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module> 
    print onerand(test)
  File "test.py", line 7, in onerand
    pack[choice(range(len(packet)))]= byte
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

So what should i do to be able to use that function on the test parameters ?

Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps it'd be a better idea to use one of the fuzzing frameworks instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `pack = packet[:]`, use `pack = list(packet)`, and then `return ''.join(pack)` at the end.

you can't replace a single byte of a string, but you can convert it to a list of characters, replace one item, and then convert back.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, strings are immutable.  You pass to function `onerand` a string, argument name `packet`, copy it giving a local name `pack` (still a string, still therefore immutable), then you try to do

```
pack[whatever] = byte
```

the index doesn't matter: you're trying to modify the immutable string.  That's what the error message is telling you, as clearly as possible it seems to me: you can't do that.

> I dont want to split in an array all
>   the byte

Well you surely can't use a **string**, if you need to assign some of them.  What do you have against arrays, anyway?  `import array`, use `pack = array.array('c', packet)` instead of `pack = packet[:]`, and live happily ever after -- an `array.array` is very compact and speedy, *and* mutable too!

**Edit**: you *could* do it with a list, as in the accepted answer, but that's only at a truly steep relative cost in performance.  Consider, for example:

```
$ py26 -mtimeit -s's="".join([str(x)[0] for x in range(99)]); import array
> ' 'a=array.array("c",s); a[23]="b"; b=a.tostring()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 usec per loop
$ py26 -mtimeit -s's="".join([str(x)[0] for x in range(99)]); import array
> ' 'a=list(s); a[23]="b"; b="".join(a)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.68 usec per loop
```

A `list` is a much more general structure than the `array.array` you really need here, whence the more-than-seven-times slowdown in choosing the wrong data structure.  (It's less terrible in Python 2.7, "only" a 4-times-plus slowdown -- but, think how much it would cost you to buy a machine four times faster than your current one, and maybe you'll agree that even speeding things up by "just" 4+ times, instead of 7+ times, is still a well-worthwhile byproduct;-).

Comment: `'b=s[:23]+"b"+s[24:]'` is almost twice as fast again

Comment: @gnibbler, yep, if you need to set only one byte in a string of moderate length.  `array` scales up better for longer strings and/or more byte-assignments required.

Comment: the trick is that its the *relative* performance cost. fast enough is fast enough, and unless he's maxing out his current machine's CPU turning strings into lists, he can save his money (he isn't - on my machine with linux running python 2.6 just the `choice(range(256))` takes twice as long as the `list` wrap, replacement, and unwrap).

another metric here though is readability/understandability, and you can't beat `list` for a widely known, widely understood, unsurprising data structure.

nonetheless, great reminder about the `array` module. it is really unfortunate that it is so obscure.